# unable to parse using pd.json_normalize, it throws null with index values

Tags: python, json, pandas, json-normalize

Sample of my data:

| ID | target |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {"abc":"xyz"} |
| 2 | {"abc":"adf"} |

this data was a csv output that i imported as below in python

```
data=pd.read_csv('location',converters{'target':json.loads},header=None,doublequote=True,encoding='unicode_escape')

data=data.drop(labels=0,axis=0)
data=data.rename(columns={0:'ID',1:'target'})
```

when I try to parse this data using

```
df=pd.json_normalize(data['target'])
```

i get Empty dataframe

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| 0 |  |
| 1 |  |

Comment: what is your expected output? how should your df look like ?

Comment: I looking to parse those JSON strings, expecting output as a data frame to have field name as 'abc' and values as xyz, adf

Comment: also in case of real data the JSON string is huge with arrays...if I just copy and paste the string to json_normalize it works as expected, but when i pass it as data['target'] it throws nulls

Comment: did you try to check: `type(data['target'][0])` to see if the values in this column are really of type `dict` ? because there is nothing wrong with your code

Comment: its a string 'str', even when i try to pass it as `pd.json_normalize(data['target'].to_dict())` I still get the same empty dataframe

Comment: sorry..in the above case `pd.json_normalize(data['target'].to_dict())` the output is like- it converts the index values to columns and all json  strings become values of 1 single row

Comment: see my answer, I think that solves your problem

Comment: btw, when reading your data, shouldn't it be `'location.csv'` ? the file ending has to be included

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the cells from strings to actual dicts and then your code works.
Try this:

```
df['target'] = df['target'].apply(json.loads)
df = pd.json_normalize(df['target'])
```

Comment: tried this..getting the  error **JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 1322 (char 1321)**

Comment: also if just copy paste the json string in the normalize function it works perfectly..so json seems to be fine.

Comment: I wouldn't say thats not possible because my knowledge about that is not deep enough, but looking at documentation and googling around make me think you can't pass a string like `'{"abc":"xyz"}'` to `json_normalize`. Soo, are you really sure you passed a string to it or did you pass a dictionary to it filled with key, values as strings.

Comment: the other thing, decodeError. Is there a special reason you use `encoding='unicode_escape'` ? I'd suggest there is an issue. I tested this code on your example and it works fine, that's why I think the problem is how you read the data with `pd.read_csv`

Comment: it worked- I guess there was issue with the way i was reading the csv

Comment: Thanks..Just read the csv normally and later applied the loading and parsing steps